Unnecessary padding TabView component
I have two TabViews which are used inside of the sheet and they are both displayed with .tabViewStyle(.page) as you can see in the code below. Basically, their structure is the same and they have the same behavior:
struct TabbedColorPicker: View {
    @Binding var selectedColor: String
    
    var allAvailablePalettes: [ColorPalette]
    var userisPremium: Bool = true
    
    private let columns: [GridItem] = [
        GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 16, alignment: .center),
        GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 16, alignment: .center),
        GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 16, alignment: .center),
        GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 16, alignment: .center),
        GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 16, alignment: .center)
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            TabView {
                ForEach(allAvailablePalettes) { palette in
                    VStack(alignment: .center) {
                        Text(palette.name)
                            .font(.system(.caption, design: .rounded))
                            .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
                            .padding(.bottom, 4)
                        
                        LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
                            ForEach(palette.colors, id: \.self) { color in
                                VStack {
                                    if (palette.isPremium && !userisPremium) {
                                        ZStack {
                                            Circle()
                                                .fill(Color[color])
                                            
                                            Image(systemName: "lock.fill")
                                                .foregroundStyle(.primary)
                                        }
                                        .frame(width: 48, height: 48)
                                    } else {
                                        Circle()
                                            .fill(Color[color])
                                            .frame(width: 48, height: 48)
                                    }
                                }
                                .tag(color)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    if (palette.isPremium && !userisPremium) {
                                        print("move to sub page")
                                    } else {
                                        selectedColor = color
                                    }
                                }
                                .padding(color == selectedColor ? 2 : 0)
                                .overlay(
                                    color == selectedColor ?
                                    Circle()
                                        .stroke(Color[color], lineWidth: 2) :
                                        nil
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }.padding()
                }
            }
            .fontDesign(.rounded)
            .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
        }
        .background(Color(UIColor.secondarySystemBackground))
        .cornerRadius(16)
    }

In two of them I have a problem with unnecessary padding on the bottom and top of them, like on the screenshot below. Interesting fact is that when keyboard is opened, then they both collapse to be visible and this padding is not visible.
Without keyboard:

With keyboard:

Is there any way to control this? Or they just take the maximum available space?
